# iOS Quartz 2D: draw an image simulating y axis rotation?

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-2d

I want to do this:
draw an image using Quartz 2D, the image look like rotated according to its y axis in a 3D space, like this:
[image]

Is Quartz 2D capable to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this directly with Quartz 2D. It supports only [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), which always preserve parallel lines.

(It's clear that you want the parallel lines on the top and bottom edges of your figure to become non-parallel.)

The term you're looking for is "perspective transformation", if you want to search for other ways to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in 2d, but its really easy to do it with quartz using this kind of call:

```
yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/4, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

You should look into using the CATransform3D's.  They are pretty powerful and easy to call.

Comment: That won't be enough. Make sure you change the m34 perspective.

Comment: That is Core Animation not quartz.

Comment: Its one line to transform the image the way he needs.  These transforms are such a handy way to do this kind of stuff.